# Are synths human for the purpose of damage calculation?

Tags: fallout-4

I realize this is a bit of a philosophical question regarding the game but that's not my intent.

I'm purely interested in whether or not my shotgun that does 50% more damage to humans will do extra damage to synths when applied to their face.

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I'd say the gen 1 and gen 2 synth aren't human, but the gen 3 ones possibly are. I have no idea if that's correct, though.

Comment: @Nolonar It is, weapons which apply bonus dmg to robots affect gen 1 and 2, but not 3

Comment: Just curious: Did you playtest the accepted answer before giving it the check-mark? Just because a Synth doesn't count as a robot, doesn't mean that it will count as a human.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I believe so. "General Chao's Sword" (+50% bonus damage to robots) does NOT affect gen 3 synths due to some bizarre oversight, so it is safe to assume that +damage to humans will affect them.

Comment: According to a comment above, gen 1 and 2 are robots, and gen 3 are humans. If that's correct, could you clarify your answer?

Comment: Gen 3 are probably human clones with implants. The whole synth story is silly. Synths are probably just cyborgs.